# JAVA calsses used in grails as objects

Tags: java, grails

Hi I have added my java classes to the

```
 projectName/src/java/MyClass.java
```

but i create an object in a service I have tried the following:

```
  def server = new MyClass();

  MyClass server = new MyClass();
```

The service cannot see the java class. Is there something more i need to do?

Comment: Have you forgot the import statements?

Comment: This should work, does your java class has a package? Maybe you need to use a package then.

Comment: Please show us more of your code. Perhaps your Groovy class is in a different package than your java class?

Comment: yeah it is in a different package. The grails package is: package com.service.Server and the java doesn't have a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is in the same `package` then you can use it right away. Otherwise, you have to `import` it.

Example:

if you have your MyClass.java as
------- MyClass.java -------------

```
package com.stackoverflow;
//rest of the class
```

------- end of MyClass.java ------

Then you can use it as
------- Mygroovy.groovy -----------------

```
import com.stackoverflow.MyClass  

//the rest of the code
```

-----------end of Mygroovy.groovy -------

Comment: I added the package to the java classes and all is well now :)